# Nested reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular application with  nested reactive form. Please verify whether my approach of nesting the form by passing the parent form reference in child is appropriate or not. Also, suggest me better approach if possible.
Below is the reference of my code. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usmwua

```
/*parent component*/
profileForm:FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    firstName:['', Validators.required],
    lastName:[''],
    address:AddressComponent.generateAddressComponent()
})

/*child component*/
static generateAddressComponent(){
   return new FormGroup({
      city:new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
   })
}
```

Comment: Its incorrect. You may make this work but this is a really bad design. Refer this link : https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Comment: It's not incorrect. I personally don't like it too, but according to this video (kara is part of `@angular/forms` team), it's fine, but with restricions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8 . I'd rather implement `ControlValueAccessor` for the address component in cases like this.

Comment: Take some time and try to implement the above link on your own. Its better to take some time rather than doing it wrong.

Comment: I said it may work but design approach is too bad. Bugs will be difficult to manage. In the link that I gave , the author creates address component . You have also a similar situation with slight difference. Read that blog well

Comment: Personally I like create the Form in parent component and pass as `@Input` the control or the group. Ah! it's not necesary create a custom form control nor use ControlValueAccessor, just `[control]="profileForm.get('adress')"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be better to pass the parent form to the child:

`<child-component [form]="profileForm">`

and add to the form group from the child component:

```
  _form: FormGroup;
  @Input()
  get form(): FormGroup {
    return this._form;
  }

  set form(val: FormGroup) {
    this._form = val;
    this._form.addControl('address', new FormGroup({
      city:new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
   }));
  }
```